# Downloading Large file to certain directory from within app using DownloadManager

Tags: java, android, download-manager

I have an application that needs to be able to download a ~3GB file to a user specified location, I currently have the below code, which seems to work.
i.e the download takes place with it showing up in the download manager etc.

However once the download is complete it fails to appear in the correct location, and the space has not been taken up at all.

This is my current code:

```
 public void file_download(String uRl) {
install_txt = AppPreferences.getPrefs().getString(
                "path",
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/test.img");

            DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    downloadUri);

            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("test")
                    .setDescription("Downloading test")
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS , install_txt);

            mgr.enqueue(request);
        }
```

So my question really is why does the above not work well? or is it just that the download manager struggles to download such large files?
If that is the case is there a better method I could use to download reliably such a large file

After the download finishes the below is shown in the logcat

```
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199): Exception for id 8952: Invalid int: "3891000000"
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "3891000000"
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.handleEndOfStream(DownloadThread.java:516)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.transferData(DownloadThread.java:314)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.executeDownload(DownloadThread.java:278)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.runInternal(DownloadThread.java:193)
07-19 13:19:28.112: W/DownloadManager(19199):   at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:142)
```

Comment: Do smaller files work OK? Are you reasonably sure it's just a problem with large files?

Comment: @KenWolf yes smaller files seem to work ok

Comment: Thanks - Are you sure there's enough space on the device?

Comment: @KenWolf yes I check for free space before running the above function, and on my test device I have 10GB free to be sure

Comment: Your `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` call is odd. Your code implies that the default value of `install_txt` will be something like `/mnt/sdcard/test.img`, which is a rather strange set of subdirectories to put in the user's `Downloads` directory. Beyond that, have you tried putting a 3GB file in your desired location by any other means, such as DDMS or **`adb push`**?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes the above code was copied wrong, I was trying to get it to download to /mnt/sdcard/test.img but couldn’t get this work either so was downloading it to the environments Download folder to test. yes I can move the file on to the device via other means

Comment: Any interesting messages in LogCat around the time the download is flagged as complete?

Comment: @CommonsWare shall have to try the download again, but I did not see anything last time

Comment: @CommonsWare seems there was some issue with it see changes to question

Comment: you can always use a library like this one here: https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-download-a-file-in-android-and-show-the-progress-very-easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message would suggest that `DownloadManager`, at present, is limited to files that are 2147483647 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) bytes or smaller.

There has been [a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41163) filed for this already, with no response from Google at present.

In the meantime, I'd see if you could arrange to split that ~3GB file into two smaller files. If not, you may need to do the downloading yourself.

Comment: Thank you, shall have to look at splitting the files